# Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006 R2 Installation Wizard Internal Error 2738

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-deployment

HI

I am getting follwing message when i try to uninstall Biztalk server 2006 R2 from Win 7 laptop.

Internal Error 2738.

The uninstaller is logging following message.

MSI (s) (60:C8) [14:15:05:338]: Product: Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006 -- Removal failed.

MSI (s) (60:C8) [14:15:05:338]: Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006. Product Version: 3.6.1404.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Removal success or error status: 1603.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While it's a supported OS, BizTalk is a server product and should be installed on one.  I recommend installing to Windows Server 2008 or 2008 R2.  I get pinged all the time with people with issues while installing and running BizTalk on Win 7.